# Running a script with arguments

Tags: r

```
product<- data.frame(products = c("spectrum, clarity, ping","lync"))
```

I have a total of 108 products in my products variable and need to run the script for 22 of those variables. Is there a way for me to subset my dataset `spectrum <- subset(product, product=="spectrum")`   for those variable from the command line? Add an argument maybe? I am sorry if my question is not clear.  I am brand new to R (been using it for about 2 weeks)

Thank you

Comment: a general solution would be to wrap the script in a function which works for one variable, and use one of r's many ways to repeat the function for each variable. Post the script that you're using or there's not much else to say

Comment: Let us help you! The clearer your question is the more likely for you to have an answer. Try posting the some data and the output you want. check dput(your data.frame).

Comment: What you looked at the `commandArgs()` function? Or `Rscript`?